# Vue2Leaflet - Can I create markers through JavaScript instead of using components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet, vue-component

From [Vue2Leaflet's document](https://korigan.github.io/Vue2Leaflet/#/components/l-marker/), a marker has to be created using `<l-marker :lat-lng="latLng" ></l-marker>`.

However, there is some need that make me have to create the marker from JavaScript instead of from `<template></template>`. So, can I use similar syntax like Google Maps? (i.e.,

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latLng,
  map: map,
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got it working. Here's what I did (excerpt):

```html
<template>
  <l-map ... ref="myMap"></l-map>
</template>
```

```
import L from 'leaflet'
import * as Vue2Leaflet from 'vue2-leaflet';
...

export default {
  ...,
  mounted() {
    const map = this.$refs.myMap.mapObject;
    L.marker([13.76, 100.5]).addTo(map);
  },
};
```

That's really it!